# Find value of $a*b$ from the given equation with $3$ variables

Tags: exponential-function

**Given equation**:

### $(2a+7)\cdot(3b +1) = (3c + 7)$

#### where $a,b,c$ are whole numbers

**Find**:

### b*a

Looking for some direction on how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left side is of this equation is always odd (except $a=0$ or $b=0$) while right side is always even. So you have to analyze these special cases.